# Friend request real time notification to recipient device

Tags: objective-c, ios, push-notification, friend

I want to notify a user if any other user wants to be friend with him. The only ways I can currently think of is notify through push notifications or recipients device will keep polling server for new information at certain frequency or device will check for new information only when it launches.

I have some problems with Push Notifications method to send requests

1. If device is offline only last notification will get processed
2. If app is not running, push notification will get delivered in Notifications and I don't know how can I extract information from there to my app.

Also, if device keeps polling for new information number of API calls will be very high which is not cost effective and alternately if device asks for new information only at start up launch it will not get real time updates.

Is there any way I can send information to device as soon as information is available?.
Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/)?

They have a great framework set up for queueing and receiving push notifications, even when your app is offline.  You can either queue the notification from the app itself or from your server hosting your account data.  They also have the ability to compose and push rich content notifications.

The basic account for small apps gets 1 million free push notifications per month.  Everything beyond that is fractions of a penny.

Hope this helps, Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for reply rwyland. But Urban Airship push notifications also store at max one push notification if device is offline and If I am using push notifications to as medium to notify friend request then some of friend request might get lost..

Answer (score 2):

Notifications is one such thing which can drain down battery if one takes polling route, thats one of the reasons Apple developed Push Notifications. I would recommend try to use Apple Push notification as much as possible as it would have been optimized to hell. If you have different flows for when the app is active & for when the app is not active (reg. notifications) you can do it like so -

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        // app active.
    }
    else {
        // app not active
    }
}
```

But if in any case Apples Technology does not suite ones needs one could always use third party services. In this case there are a few that can really help you.

[Pusher](http://pusher.com) has an [Objective-C library](https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher) and a REST API (along with a [number of libraries](http://localhost:3000/docs/rest_libraries)) that would let you push realtime updates from your server into an iOS application.

[OpenPush](http://openpush.im/) is another such service. Also check this link, here's a compiled [list of realtime technologies](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide) in which I'm sure you'll also find technologies that meet your requirements.

All of these are better than polling.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply Srikar. Just to be sure - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo is the only delegate method that handles all types of notifications from remote server(say urban airship) or this method gets called only for push notifications?

Comment: From this article -http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12 it appears that push notifications are not reliable. So  I wanted to know is there any other way than sending push notifications to device so that   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo will get called?

Comment: this delegate is used for apple push notification only. abusing `didReceiveRemoteNotification` for any other purpose other than apple push notification could cause app store rejection. I would recommend not going that route.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. As you said didReceiveRemoteNotification is used for apple push notifications only, can I assume that when Urban Airship is delivering "Rich Push Notifications" some different delegate method is called (Rich push notifications can deliver content other than just badges, alerts and sound)?

Comment: i would only hope so. apple push notification does not run on http. hence it does not run on port:80. dont know if `urban Airship` is http based. in any case you might need to implement a set of delegate methods to listen to when you get notifications from not jsut `urban Airship` but any other service you end up using...

Comment: no need to thank, i was only trying to help. if my answer has helped you please upvote or better reward me the bounty :)

Comment: Will just wait for some more time if I get alternate options and according to that will give bounty(have already upvoted the answer)

Comment: I think that all of the above methods work great for real time information exchange while you're in the app. However, they will NOT work while your app is in the background, sleeping (they might, but that would mean you will have to use your app as an VOIP app - and it will get rejected by apple). H

Answer (score 1):

*Is there any way I can send information to device as soon as information is available?. Any suggestions will be appreciated*

> user1 wants to add user2 as friend.

from device, post information to server, in your webscript, process the friend request of user1 to user2 (insert/update information to database etc), when done. send the notification to user2.  this will work if the device is offline, user2 will have real time update, if the app is running. you can run scheduled request that will check new notifications. say every 2 minutes, a method in your app runs. but thats not a very good idea. A reload button inside the app to check notification is better.

Answer (score 1):

What you would normally do is to use the push request as a means of informing your app that new data is available. The user clicks on the push notification - the app is opened with the

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

you register that there was push, query your server and the server let's your app know that this list of new friend requests are there.
You can't really do the queuing of messages on the device - and you don't need to. It's much easier to just store the info on your server until the app queries it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply LordT. Can I assume that the procedure you described is a standard one or other apps like foursquare etc have their own way of letting devices know about new data?

Comment: that's the usual way to do it on apple devices

Comment: Thanks LordT, that gave me some confidence..!! Just a small question - Web services like pusher, PubNub claim to deliver real time notifications to devices and also queue the notifications if device is offline. However APNS stores only last push notification for device, How can then these service achieve queuing of notifications?

Comment: At least PubNub is not a background push service - only apple's services are really background enabled. It's a push service for the running app so you don't have to regularly query the server but instead get new info pushed. but only while the app is in foreground.